# portlet class variable

Tags: java, jsp, portlet

http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2009/03/understanding-standard-portlet-life.html

at this page there is a sentence like: "The Portal server will create only one instance of portlet per JVM"

What does it mean? Is it means that; if i use class variable in my portlet, all users will use the same values?

I have a problem like this. I am keeping page number of a jsp page, in a class variable. And if my friend open this page with his computer, he always seeing the same page with me!!!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portlets (like servlets) can service multiple requests concurrently. They are scoped to the application and should be threadsafe.

You should not use member variables for per-user state. Request scope data should be held in the [request](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) (or possibly as [render parameters](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/javax/portlet/StateAwareResponse.html#setRenderParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)). If you want user data to persist across requests, you should use [the session](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html#getPortletSession%28%29).

Comment: Thanks. I will use render parameter i think.